# What is the best way to use unordered maps to return a summary of the elements in a vector?

Tags: c++, function, vector

Objective: I need to create a function called Summarize return a summary of the given list, i.e.,
For each value that occurred in the list, how many times it occurs ->

param list: data to be summarized

pre: list has been initialized with a certain number of
elements

post: return a summary of the list

I have a vector in my main and I am declaring this function after main.
The user enters their own vector manually or generates one automatically
and they can call the Summarize() to Summarize the vector.

If anybody can assist me, I greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euZZp.jpg)
[Summarize Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6uxN.jpg)
[Goal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxJzb.jpg)

My code will look something like this, I just cannot understand unordered maps :(

```
std::unordered_map< int, int > count_frequency( T1 first, T1 last )
{
    std::unordered_map< int, int > temp_unordered_map;
    auto temp_unordered_map_end = std::end( temp_unordered_map );
    while( first != last )
    {
        auto it_temp_unordered_map = temp_unordered_map.find( *first );
        if( it_temp_unordered_map == temp_unordered_map_end )
        {
            temp_unordered_map.emplace( *first, 1 );                       
        }
        else
        {
            ++( it_temp_unordered_map->second );
        }
        ++first;
    }
    return temp_unordered_map;
}
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<map>


using namespace std;

//Functions called before main/driver part of program
vector<int> GenerateVector(int len, int min, int max);
void PrintVector (vector<int> L, int size);
vector<int> ReadVector(int length);
void countSort(vector<int> &v);
unordered_map<int, int> Summarize(const vector<int> & list);
bool ContainDuplicate(vector<int> list);
bool IsPermutation (vector<int> list1, vector<int> list2);



//Main/Driver part of the program
int main(){

    vector<int> myVector;
    string command, askUser;
    int len, min, max, userInput;
    cout << "Welcome. This program implementes and tests three sorting algorithms on vector of integers" << endl;
    
    do{
    
    cout << "Enter a command. (generate, csort, Summarize, CheckDuplicate, Permutation, quit): "; 
    cin >> command;
    cout << "You entered: " << command << endl;
    

        if(command == "generate"){
        cout << "Do you want to generate enter the vector manually?: (Y/N) ";
        cin >> askUser;

        //The user input Y or Yes that they want to manually input the size of a vector
        if (askUser == "Y"){
            //Function that allows the user to enter a vector manually
            cout << "Enter the length of the vector: ";
            cin >> len;
            myVector = ReadVector(len);
            cout << "Your generated a vector of size " << myVector.size() << endl;
            for(int i=0;i<myVector.size();i++){
            cout << myVector[i] << endl;
            }

            
        //User does not want to manually input their own vector
        } else if (askUser == "N"){
        //prompt the user for the len of the vector
        cout << "I will generate a random vector for you. " << endl;
        cout << "What is the length of the vector: ";
        cin >> len;

        myVector = GenerateVector(len,1,99);
        cout << "Random Vector Generated: " << myVector.size() << endl; 

        for(int i=0;i<myVector.size();i++)
        cout << myVector[i] << endl;
        }






        //Counting sort
        } else if (command == "csort"){
            countSort(myVector);
             for (int x: myVector) {
            cout << x << " ";
            }
            
        }
    }while(command != "quit");
}



//Functions called after main/driver part of program


/* Generate a vector of int of given len, and return the
vector
 @param len: len of vector to be created
 @param min: minimum value
 @param max: maximum value, these specify the range for the
random numbers to be put into the vector
 @return vector of random integer values generated
 @pre: len>=1, min < max
 @post: omitted the obvious
*/
vector<int> GenerateVector (int len, int min, int max)
{
    int r;
    vector<int> L;
    //There are L max-min+1 possible ways for [min...max]
    //iterated and increment through the indexes of the user generated vector. started from index 0 to the len the user specified.
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        r = rand() % (max-min+1);

        L.push_back(r); //append L value to the front of the vector, and then next position, and onward

    }
    //return vector L
    return L;
}   


/*Print L vector of int*/
//@pre: This function will read in a vector of type int from index 0 to the end of the vector.
//@post: The vector will print out to the screen
/* Print a vector of int, e.g.,
 3 13 9 23 12 29
 */
void PrintVector (vector<int> L, int size)
{
    for(size_t i=0; i<L.size(); i++){
        cout << L[i] << " ";
    }
    cout <<" " << endl; 
 }


/*
 Read the given number of integers from cin, put them in a
vector return the vector
 @param length: length of vector to be created
 @return vector of integer values entered by the user
 @pre: length>=1
 @post: omitted the obvious */


vector<int> ReadVector(int length){

    vector<int> L;
    int userVals;
     
     cout << "Enter a vector: ";
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        cin >> userVals;
        L.push_back(userVals);
    }
    return L;
}




/*
 Read the given number of integers from cin, put them in a
vector return the vector
 @param len: len of vector to be created
 @return vector of integer values entered by the user
 @pre: len>=1
 @post: omitted the obvious */


 /* Use counting sort to sort a vector of positive int into
ascending order.
 Note: You will need to find the largest value in the list
yourself.
 @param list: the list to be sorted, list.length() gives the
size of the list
 @pre: list has been initialized with a certain number of
elements
 @post: elements in list has been arranged into ascending order
*/
  
  void countSort(vector<int> &v){
    // create an empty map to store the frequency of array elements
    map<int, int> freq;
 
    // store distinct values in the input array as key and
    // their respective counts as values
    for (int x: v) {
        freq[x]++;
    }
 
    // traverse the map and overwrite the input array with sorted elements
    // (the map will iterate based on the sorted order of keys)
    int i = 0;
    for (auto p: freq) {
        while (p.second--) {
            v[i++] = p.first;
        }
    }
}




    //ATTEMPT 1 for count sort (Caused a segmenetation fault :(!!!))
    
    /*
    //Let k be the largest element in L 
    int k = L.size()-1;
    //Let count[0…k] be a new array
    //An array called count with 99 elements 0-99
    int count[99];



   for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
         count[i] = 0;
          // count[v] stores # of occurrences of value v (used i instead, i am not sure if correct)
        
   }
   //for index 0 at j until the entire size of the vector (n-1) we want to iterate through the vector
   for(int j=0;j<k;j++){
       count[L[j]]++; //we see one more value of L[j], so increment the counter value
   }

     // make count[v] store the # of values <=v
     for(int i=1;i<k;i++){
         count[i] = count[i-1]+1; //used i instead, not sure if correct
     }
    // Create a separate vector R of same size as L
    vector<int> R;

    // place list elements to R[0…n-1], in sorted order (making use of count array)
    //for j=n-1 downto 0
    for(int j=0;j=R.size()-1;j++){
        //Using the count array to sort j list elements of vector R into ascending order (0 to n-1)
        count[R[j]++];
        int p = count[L[j]]; //L[J] is the p-th smallest number in L
        R[p-1] = L[j]; //L[j] should go to index p-1, as my index is starting from 0 
        count[L[j]] = count[L[j]]-1;
        //The above three lines can be combined into one:
        // R[-- count[L[j]] ] = L[j]
    }

      ///Copy R to L, one element at a time
     // Or You can also use vector assignment: L = R
     for(int j=0;j<R.size()-1;j++){
         L[j] = R[j];
     }
    
}
*/








/* return a summary of the given list, i.e.,
For each value that occurred in the list, how many times it
occurs
@param list: data to be summarized
 @pre: list has been initialized with a certain number of
elements
@post: return a summary of the list */
unordered_map<int, int> Summarize(const vector<int> & list){

    
}





/* Check if a given vector contains duplicate values or not.
 @param list: a list of int
 @post: return true if list contains some duplicate int values
 Return false if all int values in list are distinct
(unique)
 */
bool ContainDuplicate(vector<int> list){






return true;
}


/* Given two vectors of integers, check if the two vectors are
permutations of each other, i.e., they contains same values in
same or different order.
 V1={3,4,10,4,2,11} and V2={11,2,10,4,3,4} stores same set
of data points 
 @param list1, list2: two vectors of integers
 @pre: list1, list2 have been initialized
 @post: return true if list1 and list2 stores same values (in
same or different order); return false, if not. */
bool IsPermutation (vector<int> list1, vector<int> list2) {


return true;
}
```

Comment: Please copy paste your code instead of putting a screenshot. We cannot edit screenshot !

Comment: My apologies! I will do it now

Comment: Much better. A second helpful step is to try to reduce the amount of code you show us ;-). https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Haha thank you! I am new to this site, so I am learning

Comment: No problem ! That's why I'm giving you those comments ! Asking good question is not immediate ans as well an important step to get efficient help.

Comment: If I understand your code, you need help writing the Summarize function. So you can drop most of the remaining code. However, SO is not a site where we write code for you. You have to show us your attempt and then you'll get help.

Comment: I added some code of what I think it should look like :)